# MySql error in php code with MariaDB

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb

When I try to create new entries to a mysql table and bring variables   from one php file to another with `start_session()` I get the following error:

> Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB  server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 2

My code looks like this:

```php
session_start();  

$servername = "xxx";  
$username = "johndoe";  
$password = "password";  
$dbname = "databese";  

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", 
                    $username, $username, $password);
```

First of all there is nothing in line 2.

`session_start()` was working before with the same file when I created the table.

Any Idea?

Comment: The error is not in line two of php code. show the sql statements you are calling.

Comment: you have 2 `$username` here `$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname",$username,
$username,$password);`

Comment: delete one `$username` parameter. If still problem persist post the SQL query

Comment: "Line 2" refers to line 2 of the SQL query. The SQL query which we're not seeing. Of course MySQL doesn't know what line of PHP source code that originated from.

Answer (score 0):

And when you locate the query, look at the end of it.  I'll guess you have an extra right paren.